Restrict file select input to a single directory
Let me just start by saying, I know that there is a question like this already here. I know that, but the previous one has no answers and I have a very specific problem. And I am all ears for alternative solutions.
So I have a file-type input where I want the user to be able to chose a folder containing files. My intended usage required me to use some external scripts. Hence, I need the full path of the files that are chosen.


<Box>
  <Button variant="contained" component="label" sx={{ mb: 2 }}>
    Choose Files
    <input
      type="file"
      webkitdirectory="true"
      directory="true"
      onChange={handleFolderChange}
      multiple
      hidden
    />
  </Button>
</Box>



The issue is, react doesn't allow me to get the whole path, but just the relative path (as far as I know, due to security reasons, that can't happen as answered here).
Currently on my Flask backend I am having to join the path of my BASE_DIR to the file path. This in turn leads to the issue that my file needs to be in a certain folder on my BASE_DIR.
Right now I am solving this issue by having a check on the backend if the folder is within the BASE_DIR. But I want a more elegant solution.
So I have certain solutions in mind, but I don't know if any of them can be implemented in react:

Solution 1: I restrict the input to only show folders from my
BASE_DIR.

Solution 2: I find a way to get the whole path.

Solution 3: I build my own file-chooser, something like a collapsible
tree where a user can tick folders (only folder from my BASE_DIR
will be visible). I don't know if that is the best solution though.


Being very very new to react, I might be missing something very obvious. Hence, apologies and thanks in advance!
PS: Let me know if you think I should be renaming the question, this just seemed more appropriate.

Assuming you're expecting to get information about the file structure on the client machine, then none of the solutions you have proposed will work. What you're trying to do is simply not possible for a variety of security reasons. This is not a React or JS restriction, it's down to the browsers themselves.

Dang it! Thanks for your response! I will just try to implement the 3rd solution. Seems like the only way out...
